# My component conflicts with Auth component

Tags: php, cakephp, facebook-php-sdk, cakephp-1.2

I decided to handle the Facebook functionality into a component I wrote the following code to start my own Facebook component:

```
<?php
class FacebookComponent extends Object{
  var $name = 'Facebook';
 // var $components = array('Auth', 'Session');
  var $settings = array();
  var $controller = null;
  var $facebook;
  var $fbUid;

  function initialize(&$controller, $settings) {
    Configure::load('app.conf');
    App::import('Vendor', 'Facebook', array('file' => 'facebook/src/facebook.php'));
    $this->facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => Configure::read('FBappId'),
        'secret' => Configure::read('FBsecret')
    ));

    $this->fbUid = $this->facebook->getUser();  
  }

  function is_user(){
    if ($this->fbUid){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }   
  }
  function getLoginUrl(){
      return $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'publish_stream'));
    }

}

?>
```

Everything about auth component and the login action of users controller works fine without using the above component in users_controller.php. However, just adding the Facebook component of mine in the components list of users_controller.php via var $components, I find that login action acts in strange way:

```
function login(){       
      if (!$this->Auth->user()){
        if (empty($this->data['User']['username'])){         
          $this->Session->setFlash(__('You have to login', true), 'error_msg');
        }
        else{
          $this->Session->setFlash(__('bad login', true), 'error_msg');

        }

      }
      else{
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('correct login', true), 'done_msg');
      }
}
```

when I try to access any protected action of any controller by the Auth component, I get the login page with the message of the correct login and after re-logging again it redirects to the home page of the website.

There is another symptoms, I have navigation element which shows logout link if the user is logged in, it does not show this link on any part of the website except the login page

```
<?php if ($session->read('Auth.User.id')): ?>
    <li><?php echo $html->link($html->image('close.png') . __('logout', true), array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout', 'admin' => false), array(), null, false); ?></li>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

**I'm Using CakePHP 1.2.10 and Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.0.0) -from vendors-. I'd like to confirm that every thing go fine without the component. What's the problem?**

Comment: I have never used the FaceBook API, but I suspect that the FaceBook API is overwriting your session. A quick look at their source code shows an additional `sharedSession` option, that should be used for conflicting sessions: see the source [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php#L042)

Comment: @thaJeztah You are right. In facebook.php of the sdk and in its __construct there is a conditional statement checking for the session. The question, is how could I modify this conditional statement to deal with the CakePHP session?!

Comment: Not really sure. You may have a look at this plugin though, this version is for CakePHP 1.3 (CakePHP 2.x version is also available). Seems like the author of this plugin already has done the hard work for you, so either you could learn from the source code, or install that plugin [CakePHP FaceBook plugin](https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin/tree/cakephp1.3)